# what happened when we restart django or refresh webpage?

Tags: python, r, django, rpy2

I am using django to develop a website, I use `rpy2` to invoke a R package - [cdkr](https://github.com/rajarshi/cdkr).
This is my weird problem:

1. When I start django project, the first time I can get correct answer;
2. When I refresh the webpage or submit the same form again, it cannot work, and get these error message:

   Error in .jcall(cn, "Ljava/lang/Object;", "get", as.integer(i - 1))
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
3. I use `runserver_plus` to debug, I can run the code only once, when I run it again, I will get the same error:

**the first time I run "r_result = robjects.r(rcode)"**

```
Start calculate molecular descriptor.

Check packages.

Start interprite molecular smiles.

Start plot structure.

Start calculate descriptors of structure.

Start export descriptors. Start predict CCS values. Start output result.
```

But...

**the second time I run "r_result = robjects.r(rcode)"**

```
Start calculate molecular descriptor.

Check packages.

Start interprite molecular smiles.

Start plot structure.

Start calculate descriptors of structure. Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<debugger>", line 1, in <module> robjects.r(rcode) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 359, in __call__
    s += str.join(os.linesep, tmp)
    return s

 ...

RRuntimeError: Error in .jcall(cn, "Ljava/lang/Object;", "get", as.integer(i - 1)) : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

---

This is my python code:

```
def CalculateCCS(para, ccs_type='lipid'):
"""
calculate MetCCS using R package "MetCCSPredictor"
:param para: a string contain all input parameters from user
:param ccs_type: metCCS or lipidCCS
:return:  calculation result, a dic
"""
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
result_dic = {}
name_mapping = NAME_MAPPING_FROM_R_RESULT_TO_PY
if ccs_type=='lipid':
    importr('LipCcsPredictor')
    rcode = 'LipCCS.Pred(' + para + ')'
    r_result = robjects.r(rcode)  # trouble is here
    column_n = r_result.colnames
    for x in range(len(r_result)):
        result_dic[name_mapping.get(column_n[x], 'None')] = r_result[x]
return result_dic
```

There are two things I really want to know:

1. What's the difference between the first time run the code and the second time run the same code;
2. How can I reset the whole enviromnent, so I can run it again, but don't need to restart my django project?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Also, why are you importing the Python package in the function?

Comment: @mischi Because I only use these package in this function, it's no use to import them globally.

Comment: Do you have any ideal? Please give me a hand!

Comment: I have solved this problem, It's a bug of  package `cdkr`, see [here](https://github.com/rajarshi/cdkr/issues/44)